# Fetch() - how to show location page with redirect: follow

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, browser, fetch

the question is:

1. I sent the Fetch() with POST, this is a login form,

```
        fetch('/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: _formData,
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            redirect: 'follow'
        }).then((response) => {
            if (response.redirected) {
                 // window.location.href = response.headers.get('Location');
            }
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.info('fetch() login issue: ' + err);
        });
```

2. Then, server side responds with redirect:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.16.1
Date: Fri, 18 Sep 2020 09:33:33 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 10
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: _token=1050; Secure; HttpOnly
Location: /main/top
```

3. And what I see, - the browser requests the redirected page with GET (here it is `/main/top`), and gets full content HTML as required, I see traffic with Fiddler,
4. But this is **very very strange**, - browser gets the content, BUT NOT SHOW THE REDIRECTED PAGE!
5. (no errors in `catch` after `fetch`)

What this can be??

Comment: What you see under 3), is probably still the fetch part of the whole thing - the browser responded with a redirect, so a new _background_ request is made. Did you verify whether it goes into the if branch where you are trying to set window.location.href?

Comment: Assigning window.location.href at this point will cause an additional request then. (Not necessarily a problem, if the first one got cached properly.) But if you are in control of the server-side part of this as well, then you should rather not _redirect_, but transport the URL you want to assign to window.location.href in a JSON response.

Comment: Thank you much @CBroe, right, it in fact **causes** an additional request, but **why**? And I really want to avoid double GET to the server side, this is just ugly as I see it..); is there a way to do the same with only one GET from browser and without a "dog&pony show" with passing JSON through 200 ??

Comment: `fetch` automatically follows redirects by default, this all still happens in the background. You can use the `redirect` option to override that behavior though. If you set that to `manual`, then fetch will not follow the redirect by itself, then you get to decide what to do next yourself.